# Unable to Iterate through Swift For Loop

Tags: ios, swift, radio-button

I have a loop I have generated that I want to use as a threshold for the number of radio buttons to create. It doesn't appear that my loop is iterating (I currently have 5 as the end of the loop), as I am only seeing 1 radio button on the screen:

```
for x in 0..<5 {
        let button = KGRadioButton(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 170, width: 35, height: 35))
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.manualAction(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.tag = Int(x)
        self.view.addSubview(button)
        self.view.addSubview(self.label2)
          }
        })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CGRect(x: 20, y: 170, width: 35, height: 35)
```

This is because each button is in the same place. Increment the y value of the `CGRect` for each button so they show up below each other.

Comment: Much appreciated

Comment: Are "x" and "y" actual constraints? Will the placement I use for "x" and "y" take care of scaling on multiple devices or do I have to programmatically add layout constraints?

Comment: They are just coordinates.

Comment: When programmatically adding constraints you ignore the actual coordinates, as those are determined by the constraints at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

I think loop is iterating but you cannot see buttons because they are placed on same position.
layout each of button on different position like this.

```
let button = KGRadioButton(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 170 + x * 35, width: 35, height: 35))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!